# How to use IXIA IxNetwork 8.40 to send bi-directional traffic between CPE and router

Tags: router, nat, testing

My setup is:

IXIA -- CPE -- router -- IXIA

I have one end of the IXIA connected to CPE, and getting private IP (DHCP from CPE).
Other end is connected to router side and has public IP.
Traffic upstream from CPE to router is okay.
Traffic downstream from router to CPE is not okay.

Any pointers on how to get IXIA to work in this NAT environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took about 10 seconds to search the Internet to find [this](https://www.ixiacom.com/company/blog/validating-nat-application-aware-devices-we-have-you-covered):

> To configure NAT translation in regular testing, all you have to do is
>   open “Network Neighbourhood,”(In case you need a quick recap of the
>   BreakingPoint components, you can find them here) click on the “NAT”
>   field in the IPV4 STATIC HOSTS bucket as shown below and……. that’s it!
>
> [image]
>
> This will let BreakingPoint know that there will be a translation
>   happening and traffic selected under this Network Neighbourhood will
>   run seamlessly (as long as the NAT configuration in the firewall is
>   right). Use this newly created NAT Network Neighbourhood to test all
>   your pre-existing load and security profiles and find if there is any
>   difference in performance or security effectiveness after enabling
>   dynamic or static NAT.